# Get parent node from child node in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the name of parent that this name is (Ahmed) from its child `E_Mail`. How can get this parent name and assign its value in the variable?

[image]

Comment: Whoever did the downvote should have left a comment so the new user understands why downvoted. Please include a valid image and any code you have tried for experienced firebase users to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Sign Up").orderByChild("E_Mail").equalsTo("ahmed.elnakib96@xxxx.com");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d(TAG, key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your database will be:

```
Ahmed
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed! Have you tried my solution above?